# Remove index.php with the GET superglobal from the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller, web

I have this code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And in PHP, I grab the current url request and give it it's controller so if there was http://example.com/index.php?url=about -> this will give me the about controller so it displays the about page (MVC)

Now my question is that how can I remove the index.php?url from every page. For example I want to access the about page then I need it to be -> http://example.com/about

You can see in the htaccess that I am replacing the index.php/?url with whatever I type ($1) But it doesn't seem to work because when I request this url: (example) http://example.com/about I get Object not found! Error 404. And when I have http://example.com I get the controller_home page. However, when i type http://example.com/home it also displays error 404.

If I do this: http://example.com/?url=about or http://example.com/index.php?url=about it works find and gives me the about controller so the ?url isn't getting removed by the htaccess I guess...

Might that be an another error in my php code or what?

Kindly help me as I have been looking over this error about 10 hours and I didn't find why it is behaving like that, my friend has almost the same code and it works perfectly for him.

I am kind of new to php so it might be simple bug...
Thanks in advance for everyone that helps!

Comment: First verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Yes, I did before and tried now and it works. BTW here is how my root looks like: https://gyazo.com/7678d71f467f2a14cd54b565354112de

Comment: Put a slash before index.php in the rule, `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/?url=$1 [QSA,L]`, to make sure the index file is taken from the root.

Comment: I also did that :) However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you're editing the main apache config file (httpd.conf or apache2.conf). I know the OP is using .htaccess but just in case other people having this issue see this discussion:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

First, presumably you want to test if the requested string does NOT match a directory, NOT match a file, and NOT match a symbolic link - so you need add a "!" before the RewriteCond flags (to negate the condition). Stacked RewriteConds are linked with an implicit AND so checking for directory, file and symbolic link doesn't make sense (a given requested string wouldn't match all of these conditions).

Second, the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} would be necessary if you're doing this in the main apache config file (ie/httpd.conf or apache2.conf). It's not necessary if you're doing this in an .htaccess file.

Third, when RewriteRule is matching it includes the /. Presumably when you request "website.com/about" you want "about" to be passed to index.php not "/about", so the "/?" will remove the / in first character position from $1. I put the question mark, just because I think it's best practice, since technically you could get an HTTP request that does not begin with a slash (although this would be against standards and every browser includes a slash at the beginning).

Fourth, you shouldn't put a / after the index.php in RewriteRule (so it should be "index.php?url=$1", not "index.php/?url=$1". Query strings are separated from a filename via a "?" not a "/?".

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for taking time answering my question and even explaining how it works! I highly appreciate it :) Now I pretty much know why it didn't work at first, thank you.

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((.*)+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Didn't work. Also, thanks for everybody who is helping

Comment: My friend, you are a legend! May I just ask you to explain it a bit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help! I'd like to explain that, but I'm afraid I can't. I just looked through some old code of mine and searched for a rewrite example that worked with your situation. Maybe someone else from SO is able to explain that and/or come up with an even cleaner solution.

Comment: Well, no problem. And thanks again. 

If someone knows how this works then kindly speak up :)